# Holder inequality Proof Explanation

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, holder-inequality

[image]

I don't understand why

> $$ptf(x)h(x)^{p-1}\leq (h(x)+tf(x))^p-h(x)^p$$.

Comment: Follows from the lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Thomas Shelby](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/588038/thomas-shelby)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553353/holder-inequality-proof-explanation#comment7307013_3553353) states, it follows from the lemma of

$$(a + tb)^p \ge a^p + ptba^{p-1} \implies ptba^{p-1} \le (a + tb)^p - a^p \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Using $a = h(x)$ and $b = f(x)$ in \eqref{eq1A} gives what you're asking about, i.e.,

$$ptf(x)h(x)^{p-1}\leq (h(x)+tf(x))^p-h(x)^p \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$